# Does data get lost during the MP3 quantization process

Tags: algorithm, encoding, mp3, coefficients, quantization

During the MP3 encoding process, before the data is quantized, it passes through a windowing and MDCT function. I'm wondering, does the quantization of that data mean some of it gets lost?

[MP3 Encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiuJ2.png)

Comment: You may want to (also) post this over on [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MP3 is a [lossy compression format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression).